# Rails how to make a scope to filter for a json key in a column

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, scope

In one of my columns I have a json object like this:

```
{"name":"test", "age":'12'}
```

This data is in my column. I want to make a scope to select for all records that have `age: 12`. How can I make a rails scope to filter out based on a json key in this column. I was trying something like

```
scope :age_filter, -> {where(column["age"]: 12)}
```

however this results in a syntax error; im not sure how else I should go about a secenario like this since the value in the column is a json object rather than a single value.

Comment: What database are you using, and what is the type of the column?

Comment: @Schwern the type of the column is jsonb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query JSON using your database's [JSON operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

For example, if this is a Postgres JSON column called `data`...

```
scope :age_filter, ->{ where("data->>'age' = ?", 12) }
```

Alternatively, you can use [`jsonb_accessor`](https://github.com/madeintandem/jsonb_accessor).

```
scope :age_filter, ->{ data_where(age: 12) }
```

Note: I would advise using regular columns where possible and only use JSON for free-form data. While jsonb-accessor helps, Ruby on Rails is not well integrated with JSON and traditional columns will be less hassle. In your example above, `age` should be a normal integer column.